# If $G$ is a connected simple graph and mean of degrees is $2$. How many cycle in $G$?

Tags: graph-theory

Proof:

Let G is connected simple graph with n vertex and $\sum \dfrac{d(v)}{n}=2$.Since $\sum{d(v)} =2ε(G)$ then $n=ε(G)$.
I want to prove that $G$ has cycle by contradiction.Let $G$  has no cycle, I get $G$ is tree with $n$ vertex then $G$ has $n-1$ edges but $G$ has $n$ edges  that mean $G$ has cycle
and I have no idea to proof how many cycle in $G$.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show that $G$ must have *a* cycle, or find the number of cycles? If it's the first one, the calculate $\varepsilon(T)$ when $T$ is a tree to get your contradiction.

Comment: I try to find the number of cycles

Comment: i think G has only one cycle but i dont know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly figured out that $G$ has $n$ vertices and $n$ edges. If $G$ is connected, then it has a spanning tree $T$. Since $T$ has exactly $n-1$ edges, there is exactly one edge $e$ in $E(G)\setminus E(T)$. Since there are no cycles in $T$, any cycle in $G$ must contain the edge $e$. In fact there is just one such cycle; it is formed by the edge $e$ and the unique path in $T$ which connects the endpoints of $e$.

Comment: thank you very much